# Command Syntax for Processstartinfo from variables

Tags: c#, syntax, processstartinfo

Can someone please help me out with the syntax here

```
string sourcePath = @textBox2.Text.ToString();
string targetPath = @textBox1.Text.ToString();

System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(@"XCOPY C:\folder D:\Backup\folder /i");

psi.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
System.Diagnostics.Process copyFolders = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(psi);
copyFolders.WaitForExit();
```

I am trying to change this line below to replace c:\folder with (sourcePath) and `D:\Backup\folder` with targetPath

```
(@"XCOPY C:\folder D:\Backup\folder /i");
```

I keep getting source not found when I messagebox like this it looks ok

```
MessageBox.Show(@"XCOPY " + (sourcePath) + (targetPath) + " /i");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to debug, I'd start here:

```
string args = string.format("{0} {1} /i", sourcePath, targetPath);
Debug.WriteLine(args);
//verify your paths (both) are correct

string cmd = string.format("XCOPY {0}", args);
Debug.WriteLine(cmd);
//copy the command and test it out directly in cmd
```

Also, try passing your arguments....as arguments....

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi = 
  new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("XCOPY", args);
```

You can look at [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2) for an example of passing with arguments

Comment: Thanks Mike C that works using this code

                    string args = (sourcePath) + " " + (targetPath);

                    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("XCOPY", args + " /i");

Answer (score 0):

Nothing there really looks wrong. Perhaps debug it so you can get the text out of it and copy/paste it to Explorer to make sure the paths are valid and there's nothing funky going on?

Also, you don't need to do `.ToString()` on the `.Text` property of a TextBox. it's already a string.